# Interactive Mandelbrot set pictures

Tags: java, performance, beginner, fractals

The purpose of this project is to generate an interactive [Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set). The user can specify the degree of magnification from the command-line and click on the produced picture to magnify the picture at that point.

Here is a data-type implementation for Complex numbers:

```
public class Complex
{
    private final double re;
    private final double im;

    public Complex(double re, double im)
    { 
        this.re = re; 
        this.im = im; 
    }
    public double re() 
    { 
        return re; 
    }
    public double im()
    { 
        return im; 
    }
    public double abs()
    { 
        return Math.sqrt(re*re + im*im); 
    }
    public Complex plus(Complex b)
    {
        double real = re + b.re;
        double imag = im + b.im;
        return new Complex(real, imag);
    }
    public Complex times(Complex b)
    {
        double real = re*b.re - im*b.im;
        double imag = re*b.im + im*b.re;
        return new Complex(real, imag);
    }
    public Complex divide(Complex b)
    {
        double real = (re*b.re + im*b.im) / (b.re*b.re + b.im*b.im);
        double imag = (im*b.re - re*b.im) / (b.re*b.re + b.im*b.im);
        return new Complex(real, imag);
    }
    public boolean equals(Complex b)
    {
        if (re == b.re && im == b.im) return true;
        else                          return false;
    }
    public Complex conjugate() 
    {
        return new Complex(re, -1.0*im);
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return re + " + " + im + "i";
    }
}
```

Here is my program:

```
import java.awt.Color;

public class InteractiveMandelbrot {
    private static int checkDegreeOfDivergence(Complex c) {
        Complex nextRecurrence = c;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
            if (nextRecurrence.abs() >= 2) return i;
            nextRecurrence = nextRecurrence.times(nextRecurrence).plus(c);
        }
        return 255;
    }
    private static Color[] createRandomColors() {
        Color[] colors = new Color[256];
        double r = Math.random();
        int red = 0, green = 0, blue = 0;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            red = 13*(256-i) % 256;
            green = 7*(256-i) % 256;
            blue = 11*(256-i) % 256;
            colors[i] = new Color(red,green,blue);
        }
        return colors;
    }
    private static void drawMandelbrot(double x, double y, double zoom) {
        StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();
        
        Color[] colors = createRandomColors();
        
        int resolution = 1000;
        int low = -resolution / 2;
        int high = resolution / 2;
        double xLowScale = x + zoom*(1.0 * low / resolution);
        double xHighScale = x + zoom*(1.0 * high / resolution);
        double yLowScale = y + zoom*(1.0 * low / resolution);
        double yHighScale = y + zoom*(1.0 * high / resolution);
        StdDraw.setXscale(xLowScale, xHighScale);
        StdDraw.setYscale(yLowScale, yHighScale);

        for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
            for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {
                double realPart = zoom*(1.0 * i / resolution) + x;
                double imaginaryPart = zoom*(1.0 * j / resolution) + y;
                Complex c = new Complex(realPart,imaginaryPart);
                int degreeOfDivergence = checkDegreeOfDivergence(c);
                Color color = colors[degreeOfDivergence];

                StdDraw.setPenColor(color);
                double radius = 1.0 / (resolution * 2 / zoom);
                StdDraw.filledSquare(realPart, imaginaryPart, radius);
            }
        }
        StdDraw.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = Double.parseDouble(args[0]);
        double y = Double.parseDouble(args[1]);
        int magnifier = Integer.parseInt(args[2]);
        double zoom = 1;

        drawMandelbrot(x, y, zoom);

        while (true) {
            if (StdDraw.isMousePressed()) {
                x = StdDraw.mouseX();
                y = StdDraw.mouseY();
                zoom = zoom/magnifier;

                drawMandelbrot(x, y, zoom);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[StdDraw](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html) is a simple API written by the authors of the book *Computer Science An Interdisciplinary Approach*. I checked my program and it works. Here is one instance of it.

Input: 0.5 0.5 10

Output (actually a succession of outputs):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I used paint to show where I clicked.

From my own previous posts, I already know how to improve `Complex`. In this post, I am solely interested in the improvement of `InteractiveMandelbrot`. Is there any way that I can improve my program?

Thanks for your attention.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Performance: the Complex class

You've mentioned that you already know how to improve it, but the single biggest performance improvement to this program is *removing the Complex class*. Perhaps it's sad to say goodbye to that class, but run some performance tests and decide.

On my PC, at the point/zoom `0.5, 0.5, 10`, the original code runs in 100 - 110 ms per frame. Excluding drawing time, I removed that and just save the colors to an array. Excluding the first run, which is slower as is usual with Java.

If I write the complex arithmetic inline, without fundamentally changing it, like this:

```
private static int checkDegreeOfDivergence(double r, double i) {
    double a = r, b = i;
    
    for (int j = 0; j < 255; j++) {
        if (Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b) >= 2) return j;
        
        double nextA = a * a - b * b + r;
        double nextB = a * b + b * a + i;
        a = nextA;
        b = nextB;
    }
    return 255;
}
```

Now it runs in 30 - 40ms per frame. Around 3 times as fast, just by simple refactoring.

The logic can be slightly optimized, but the improvement from this is much less significant.

```
private static int checkDegreeOfDivergence(double r, double i) {
    double a = r, b = i;
    
    for (int j = 0; j < 255; j++) {
        if ((a * a + b * b) >= 4) return j;
        
        double nextA = a * a - b * b + r;
        double nextB = a * b * 2 + i;
        a = nextA;
        b = nextB;
    }
    return 255;
}
```

Comment: Just wow! It's a great perspective. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

### Comment 1

You are not using the `r` variable in `createRandomColors` , so there is nothing random in it.

### Comment 2

```
if (nextRecurrence.abs() >= 2) return i;
```

You should use brackets after `if`, don't try to be smart by writing one-liners like this. It will bite you one day when you misread it or edit it without noticing.

### Comment 3

```
for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
    for (int j = low; j < high; j++) {
        double realPart = zoom*(1.0 * i / resolution)
```

The calculation `zoom * 1.0 / resolution` is calculated 3 times in this double `for` loop, that's for every pixel on screen I think. It might be worth optimizing your calculations by taking out this factor and calculating it just once.

Since it doesn't depend on `i` or `j`, you could take this calculation out of the loop entirely and so you would calculate it once per screen instead of 3*millions times.

Likewise, the `realPart` does not depend on `j`, so calculate it outside of the `j` loop to save yourself 999/1000 (approximately) calculations for `realPart`.

`double realPart = zoom*(1.0 * i / resolution) + x;`